# Differential Forms on submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

Say I take an embedded submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$, like the sphere. Any differential form on $\Bbb R^n$ can be restricted to the sphere. My question is this: is any differential form on the sphere (or any embedded submanifold) the restriction of a form on $\Bbb R^n$? My gut says no, but I can't think of any counter examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Since the product of a form and a smooth function is again a form, extend the form to a small tubular neighborhood of your submanifold and multiply by a bump function.

---

Georges Elencwajg has suggested I explain further. To extend a $p$-form $\omega\in\Omega^p(M)$ to a $p$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we need to first define a $p$-form on $T\mathbb{R}^n|_{M}$, the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $M$.

We define such a form by splitting $T\mathbb{R}^n|_M$ into $TM\oplus \nu(M)$, the sum of $TM$ and the normal bundle of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. With this splitting, any vector $T_x\mathbb{R}^n|_M$ decomposes into tangent and normal components: $v = v^t + v^n$.

Now simply define the extension $\hat{\omega}$ to be $\omega$ on $TM$ and $0$ on $\nu(M)$. Precisely, $$\hat{\omega}(v_1,\ldots,v_p) = \omega(v_1^t,\ldots,v_p^t).$$

The normal bundle $\nu(M)$ is diffeomorphic to a small neighborhood $U$ of $M$ by traveling along the normal directions a short distance. Define the projection $\pi: U\to M$ by mapping a point $p$ to the closest point in $M$.  Extend $\hat{\omega}$ from $T\mathbb{R}^n|_M$ to $TU$ by defining it, again, to be $\omega$ applied to vectors parallel to $M$ and zero on vectors parallel to the normal direction.
(That is, the pullback of $\hat{\omega}$ by $\pi$.)

Finally, multiply $\hat{\omega}$ on $TU$ by a smooth cutoff function supported on $U$ to obtain a smooth form on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

(The Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives natural choices of bundle splittings. We also assume that $M$ is embedded, so that the construction of $U$ is possible.)

Comment: Of course! Thanks, this is perfect.

Comment: Dear Neal, OP and upvoter: this answer does not make sense. One  cannot "extend" a differential form on the submanifold $M$ to any point outside of the submanifold and certainly not to an open neighbourhood (tubular or not, which is irrelevant to the problem) of the submanifold. You must realize that the given differential form does not give a differential form on $\mathbb R^n$ *even at points on $M$*

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg I do not follow this last point: if $\omega$ is a $p$-form on a submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, define $\hat{\omega}$ on the tangent bundle of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the rule that $\hat{\omega}$ on $TM$ is $\omega$ and $\hat{\omega}$ on the normal bundle is zero. Since any vector decomposes into a sum of normal and tangent vectors, $v=v^n + v^t$, then $\hat{\omega}(v_1,\ldots,v_p) = \hat{\omega}(v_1^n,\ldots,v_p^n) + \hat{\omega}(v_1^t,\ldots,v_p^t)$ seems a perfectly well-defined $p$-form to me. Though perhaps I have not yet had enough coffee this morning.

Comment: Dear Neal, yes you can extend (in many ways) $\omega\in \Gamma(M,\Omega^p_M)$ to $\hat \omega\in \Gamma(M,\Omega^p_{\mathbb R^n}|M)$, but you should carefully explain in your answer the subtle point that it is $\hat \omega $ that you extend to some neighbourhood of $M$, not $\omega$. By the way, the formula you give in the comment is a bit awkward  since it does not involve $\omega$. What you mean is better expressed as  simply $\hat \omega (v_1,...,v_n)=\omega (v_1^t,...,v_n^t)$.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you for your suggestion. Does this edit appear a better explanation?

Comment: Dear Neal: excellent, +1 !

Comment: "$TU$ is isomorphic to $T\mathbb{R}^n |_M$" - if $M = S^1$ and $U$ is an annulus $\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, the dimension of $TU$ would be $4$ and the dimension of $T\mathbb{R}^2 |_{S^1}$ would be $3$, right?

Comment: @ougoah Thank you for observing this. I've edited my answer, I hope it's clearer.